# Converting Specific Pages of a Google Sheet to PDF Format

Tags: pdf, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a problem exporting a Google Sheets (I only want to export 2 pages of the Google Sheets) to a PDF using a LIEN_HYPERTEX and a code in Apps Script.

I used this code:

```
function PRINTURL() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit.*$/, '');

    // Obtenez les IDs des feuilles à exporter
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Note de Frais');
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Factures');

    // Construisez l'URL d'exportation avec les IDs des feuilles
    var exportUrl = url + 'export?exportFormat=pdf' +
                    '&format=pdf' +
                    '&size=letter' +
                    '&portrait=true' +
                    '&fitw=true' +
                    '&sheetnames=false' +
                    '&printtitle=false' +
                    '&pagenum=false' +
                    '&gridlines=false' +
                    '&fzr=false' +
                    '&gid=' + sheet1.getSheetId() + 
                    '&gid=' + sheet2.getSheetId(); // Essayez d'ajouter plusieurs gids

    return exportUrl;
}
```

but it only export one page it's like  the function `&gid` doesn't work.